# Problemas con funcion php

Tags: php

Mi pregunta es por que esta funcion siempre me retorna 0 despues de que se ejecuta por segunda vez

en datos envio 452,luego 452 y este me retorna 1 pero si envio en datos 453 o 454 o cualquier otro valor este siempre retorna 0

```
 public function productoTemp($datos){

       if (isset($_SESSION['tablaComprasTemp'])) {
         $datosT=$_SESSION['tablaComprasTemp'];

    for ($i=0; $i < count($datosT) ; $i++) { 
          $d=explode("||", $datosT[$i]);

          if ($d[4]==$datos) {
            return 1;
          }else{
            return 0;
          }

     }
       }

     }
```

al retornar siempre 0 me deja agregar productos repetidos

```
echo $productoTemp=self::productoTemp($datos2);

  if ($productoTemp==1){

        echo  json_encode($response = array('responsenum' =>  "-1",
          'response' =>  "No puedes tener dos productos repetidos"));

  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

$datos 2 contiene el id del producto

```
 echo $productoTemp=self::productoTemp($datos2);

  if ($productoTemp==1){

        echo  json_encode($response = array('responsenum' =>  "-1",
          'response' =>  "No puedes tener dos productos repetidos"));

  }else{

  $cantidaddb=$respuesta[0]["cantidad"];

  if($cantidaddb>=$datos){

$nombre=$respuesta[0]["nombre"];
  $valor=$respuesta[0]["valor"];
  $datos;
  $datos2;
  $datos3=$datos*(int)$respuesta[0]["valor"];


  $articulo=$nombre."||".
        $datos."||".
        $valor."||".
        $datos3."||".
        $datos2;

  $_SESSION['tablaComprasTemp'][]=$articulo;


  echo  json_encode($response = array('responsenum' =>  "1",
          'response' =>  "Producto Agregado"));

  }else{

     echo  json_encode($response = array('responsenum' =>  "-1",
          'response' =>  "Stock no tiene suficientes productos"));

  }
```

Comment: Que estas declarando en la variable `$datos` en tu `if ($d[4]==$datos)` ?

Comment: $datos es el mismo que 452 es el parametro que le paso

Comment: Por qué no pasas la variable `$datos` como argumento? en vez de **452**

Comment: Asegúrate que estés comparando los mismos tipos de datos.

Comment: Que array es el que guardas en tu variable de sesión?

Comment: $[4] siempre me esta mostrando el primer valor que se almacena en el session array y no se por que

Comment: @AlbertoJulioArceEscolar Puedes mostrar qué es lo que guardas en tu variable de sesión.

Comment: apesar de que le envio 451 y 455 el en el session siempre trae el mismo valor

Comment: osea  $d[4] siempre trae el valor de 452

Comment: y si haces solo un ` echo $d[4] ." | "  . $datos;` y ves como estas trabajando :v

Comment: No entiendo para nada el tipo de validación tan extraño que intentas implementar. Es muy raro combinar un `for` con un `explode`  y con `return` dentro. Creo que convendría refinar un poco más tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentado responder casi a ciegas, ya que no sé que es lo que trae tu variable de sesión, supongo trae una cadena como la variable `$datosT` que estoy creando, ya que utilizas un explode y el explode convierte una cadena a un array, entonces manejando esa lógica hice lo siguiente, primero para hacer la prueba creo una variable `$datosT` la cuál contiene una cadena (tomando la referencia de números 450, 451, 452, etc.), y los separo por el caracter `||`, utilizo la funcion explode y después en el for hago el `count` de mi variable `$d` que ya es un array, después en el `if` recorro mi array y hago la validación si `$d[$i] es igual a $datosT` (que es el valor que paso como argumento que a su vez es una cadena '452') si encuentra la coincidencia te va a retornar un `true` y cuando imprimas tu función `echo productoTemp($datos);` te va a imprimir un 1 en pantalla, espero te sirva o te oriente a lo que deseas realizar, suerte.

```
<?php  


$datos = '452';
function productoTemp($datos){

       /*if (isset($_SESSION['tablaComprasTemp'])) {
         $datosT=$_SESSION['tablaComprasTemp'];*/
$datosT = '450||451||452';

$d = explode('||', $datosT);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($d) ; $i++) { 

          if ($d[$i]==$datos) {
            //echo 1;
            return true;
          }/*else{
        return false;

          }*/

     }
       //}

    }
//$datos = '452';

echo productoTemp($datos);

?>
```

Comment: si en teoria debe funcionar el problema es que ese $_SESSION['tablaComprasTemp']; que contiene '450||451||452'; en mi codigo al comparar siempre me muestra el primero en este caso seria el 450.  Osea que si coloco 450 arriba la comparacion siempre va hacer true ya que en el session siempre me muestra es el primero

Comment: Lo acabas de decir te va a mostrar `true` o arrojar **1** porque a encontrado una coincidencia, si no encuentra no te imprime nada `' '`, ya intentaste poner la función explode fuera del for, así como lo respondí?

Comment: $d = explode('||', $datosT); esta parte da error por que tengo esto $datosT=$_SESSION['tablaComprasTemp']; cada vez que yo envio un codigo se llena el session la idea es que cuando el recorra el session si el codigo ya esta repetido dentro de este no lo deje guardar

Comment: arriba detallo mas el codigo si retorna uno muestra no debe repetir pero si muestra lo contrario el llena el session la idea es llenar el session sin codigos repetidos